# How to handle post response from external auth application in React router

Tags: reactjs

When users reach my application, I redirect them to my company's authentication website that authenticates the user and redirects back to my application.  The result is a POST back to my React application with a valid JWT, but I'm unsure how to handle a POST request with my React router.  Ideally, I'd like to set up a /response path that I can use to retrieve, validate, and store the JWT, but just adding the route doesn't seem to work.  Getting the error "Cannot POST /response".  I should add that I'm unable to have users enter their credentials into my app and then use something like ajax to validate the credentials and retrieve the token.  The requirement is to redirect users to the auth website and accept the redirect upon successful login.

index.js:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import 'react-grid-layout/css/styles.css'
import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css'
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route  } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AppProvider } from './context/app-context';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Agent from './pages/Agent';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import history from './history';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
<AppProvider>
    <Router history={history}>
        <React.Fragment>
                <Route path="/login" component={ Login }/>
                <Route path="/response" component={ Response }/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={ Dashboard }/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/customer/:id" component={ Agent }/>                    
        </React.Fragment>
    </Router>
</AppProvider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: You need to listen to post requests on the server. You can't do this with client side routing.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense Ok, thanks

Comment: Still not sure why a post is even attempted.  The redirect url is https://localhost:3000/response.  When the redirect happens after authentication, the address bar reads "https://localhost:3000/response#accesstoken=......".  Why would this result in a post?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track down the cause of this issue.  The oauth2 authorize call had response_mode set to "form_post" instead of "form_get".  (oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/response&response_mode=form_post ...)

After changing the value to form_get, my route is working.

Comment: is this approach safe?